# how to update flashplayer in chromium?

Tags: 14.04

i downloaded `install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz` from adobe flash website.

tried

```
tar -zxvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
```

this error popped up

```
tar (child): install-flash-player-11-linux.x86-64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

i need help on how to install it. do i have the correct file?

Comment: You should use `pepper flash` for `chromium-browser`. Refer [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/install-pepper-flash-chromium-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this utility call alien?  Alien can convert tar.gz to deb pack, which you can install through software center.  This gentleman made a video on how to use this utility.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pt44bAP2rMg

sudo apt-get install alien

### go to tar.gz directory

(sudo) alien -d packagename.tar.gz # may not need sudo, just in case

Open tar.gz directory, and now you should have a deb package.  Double click the deb package, and installation should start in software center

Best of luck.